# Neo4j 3.2.1 Neo.TransientError.Transaction.DeadlockDetected

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to execute the following Cypher in order to clear the db:

```
MATCH(n) DETACH DELETE n
```

but it fails with a following error:

```
LockClient[22488] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(159950), hash=747832011] since => LockClient[22488] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(72), hash=1038598873] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[22490] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(159950), hash=747832011]
```

What can be a reason of this and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means another thread is modifying data in the db, because you try to lock the whole db, then any other operation might have already acquired a lock.

Solution: prevent any other source of connection to the db during this operation.